# WPF Datagrid scrolling edited row data is not maintained

Tags: wpf, scroll, wpfdatagrid

I am having a datagrid which is scrollable, I have used templates to design it.
The columns are not autogenerated
I tried binding the data to datagrid with both ItemsSource and DataContext. 
I have 2 columns which are editable to user out 10 columns.
When an user edits the data of rows and scrolls up/down the data edited moves into another row.
i.e. if i edit a row say row no. 1 and then scroll down to row no. 15 and edit it.
the row no. 1 data is lost and is seen in another row, say row no. 10.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: We need way more information than this to diagnose your problem, especially as it is most likely a bug in your code. You need to post some code to show your issue.

Comment: Got the solution added EnableRowVirtualization="false" and EnableColumnVirtualization="false".....and it works..

Answer (score 0):

Check the Binding property of datagrid. make sure that the editable fied have binding set to 
"Twoway".